# Kafka broker goes out of sync for random partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a setup of 4 Kafka brokers. Each partition in each topic in my setup has a replication factor of 2. All partitions are balanced - Leaders and followers are uniformly distributed

This setup has been running for over 6 months

While monitoring the setup via Kafka Manager I see that 8% of my partitions are under-replicated.

All these partitions were assigned to the same set of replicas. And every partition which was assigned to this set of replicas is displayed as under-replicated

Lets call this set of brokers as [1,2] - broker 1 and 2. The ISR for all these partitions is [1] right now.

Both brokers 1 and 2 are up and running. All other partitions have the ISR count as expected.

The script `bin/kafka-topics.sh` also shows 8% of partitions to be under replicated.

But the jolokia metric - `UnderReplicatedPartitions` - is 0

I need help to answer -

1. Is there an issue?
2. Why is there an inconsistency in the jolokia metric and kafka console?
3. How can I fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything about "jolokia metric" but we experienced the same because we had a "slow" broker which was lagging behind with replicating the data.

"Slow" meaning that the replication requests somes breached the broker-wide configuration [replica.lag.time.max.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) which defaults to 10 seconds and is described as:

> "If a follower hasn't sent any fetch requests or hasn't consumed up to the leaders log end offset for at least this time, the leader will remove the follower from isr"

Slightly increasing this configuration solved the problem for us.